# AutoCAD .net Customization: Is there an entget equivalent for .net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I can find very little information about manipulating or reading AutoCAD shape entities using a .net language.  What I really want to do is simply retrieve the name of a shape (as it is defined in the SHX (SHP) file) from its "ShapeNumber".  I started down this rabbit hole as I was writing a simple little .net extension for gathering all of the linetypes in a file and sending their definitions to a *.lin file.  I have just about everything working except for retrieving the names of shapes used in complex linetypes.

Basically, my little program iterates through the records in the linetype symbol table and pulls all of the properties from each table record and formats them into the standard *.lin file text.  I can get a shape's number directly from the linetype's table record, but I have not found a method for getting its name.  (The shx compiler must convert the shape name to its number.)

I tried instantiating an empty shape object, assigning the shapenumber to the object, and then retrieving its name property, but that did not work (as I fully expected since it was not instantiated using a constructor that could resolve the shapenumber into a name).

I suspect that the answer could lie in the dxf entity codes for the shape (e.g. Code 2), but I don't know how to access the dxf codes from .net. Is there an autocad .net function equivalent to the ENTGET function in autolisp?  If I could get that far and find the dxf block that holds that particular shape definition from its shapenumber, I should be able to get the shape name from the entget list.

Answer (score 3):

From [this topic](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/how-to-get-min-max-and-step-of-a-distance-parameter-in-a-dynamic/m-p/12335097/highlight/true#M79227).

```
public static class Extension
{
    // Replace the DLL name according to the AutoCAD targeted version
    // 2013-2014:   "acdb19.dll"
    // 2015-2016:   "acdb20.dll"
    // 2017:        "acdb21.dll"
    // 2018:        "acdb22.dll"
    // 2019-2020:   "acdb23.dll"
    // 2021-2024:   "acdb24.dll"
    // Replace the EntryPoint according to AutoCAD plateform
    // 32 bits:     "?acdbGetAdsName@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@AAY01JVAcDbObjectId@@@Z"
    // 64 bits:     "?acdbGetAdsName@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@AEAY01_JVAcDbObjectId@@@Z"
    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("acdb24.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
        EntryPoint = "?acdbGetAdsName@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@AEAY01_JVAcDbObjectId@@@Z")]
    static extern AcRx.ErrorStatus acdbGetAdsName(out AdsName ename, ObjectId id);

    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("accore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
        EntryPoint = "acdbEntGet")]
    static extern IntPtr acdbEntGet(AdsName ename);

    public static ResultBuffer EntGet(this ObjectId id)
    {
        var errorStatus = acdbGetAdsName(out AdsName ename, id);
        if (errorStatus != AcRx.ErrorStatus.OK)
            throw new AcRx.Exception(errorStatus);
        var result = acdbEntGet(ename);
        if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
            return ResultBuffer.Create(result, true);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: GileCAD, I appreciate this so much.  I would never have been able to get that far on my own.  I'm just an engineer who likes to write code for my own personal (and my business') uses.  Although I have written code using AutoLISP, vba, and both of the most common flavors of .net, nothing involving entry points so far.  I am fortunate that someone would take the time to give me a little hand on this.  Thank you  very much.  I intend to give this a try today if I get some time.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with that some time ago. The only way I found was to import it from external DLL. Probably I found it somewhere but now I don't remember where. I would link and honour all the copyrights but don't know where and who. So to answer by code try this:

```
[DllImport("acdb19.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,  EntryPoint = "?acdbGetAdsName@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@AEAY01_JVAcDbObjectId@@@Z")]
extern static public ErrorStatus acdbGetAdsName(out Int64 entres, ObjectId id);


[DllImport("acCore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static IntPtr acdbEntGet(out Int64 e);
```

.....

```
ObjectId id = initializeObjectIdByYourObjectLinetypeMaybe();
Int64 e = new Int64();
IntPtr p = new IntPtr();
if (acdbGetAdsName(out e, id) == ErrorStatus.OK)
{
    p = acdbEntGet(out e);
    ResultBuffer rb = ResultBuffer.Create(p, true);
    return rb;
}
```

Maybe in differend version and CAD platforms other entrypoints will be needed.

Comment: See my comments to gileCAD above.  I will get to your suggestions today or possibly tomorrow depending upon how this day wraps up.  As I am mostly self-taught (other than intro to C++ in college and whatever one picks up in advanced linear algebra courses), I value insight from someone who writes code as their main occupation or who has been formally educated in the field.  Thank you very much for your help.  Sorry that it won't let me vote both of your suggestions up.  Even if they don't 100% solve the issue, I can see these answers will get me very close to what I want to do.

Comment: In case you were curious about how my little project is going:  it turned out that I could not use either approach because I am not working with an entity that exists in some space but just the reference to a shape.  Hence, the getent idea won't work.  But it did allow me to back into a solution.  My first idea actually worked, but it required that I do not just declare a shape object, but I had to insert an empty shape into model space at some arbitrary coordinates.  Then I could assign the shape number and retrieve the shape name.  It worked!  Now I need only to determine the rotation type.